# how to accomplish this border effect in css?

Tags: html, css

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aronlilland/bsmL1kx7/

for many moons now i have been trying to find out how to make the following border effect around the elements in CSS, specifically the borders between each line item like "signature serveice". "facebook monitor" etc. can i acheive this look by spacing div row 1px appart from the one below it? or how would i best accomplish this? to me it seems like there is a light color edge border around each shape, simple question, simple answer

thank you!

[image]

```
    .table {
      background: #1e2129;
      width: 375px;
    }
    .row1 {
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 100px;
      background: #272a34;
      margin-bottom: 1px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: helvetica;
    }
    .row2 {
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 100px;
      background: #313641;
      margin-bottom: 1px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: helvetica;
    }
```

Comment: Which border are you referring to? The one between the elements? Or the overall one?

Comment: ones between the elements, my bad

Comment: So, like, `border-radius` ?

Comment: Looks like just a light border at the top and a dark border at the bottom. Both solid, both nothing fancy...

Comment: @GolezTrol looks like it might also have some clever use of inset `box-shadow`s, which are actually a favorite of mine for cheap 3D effects

Comment: @abluejelly I thought so too, at first, but at second glance I thought it was actually some jpeg artifacts.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yeah you're right. Damn. Debating posting the box-shadow method anyways just because it's so much cleaner and doesn't limit your color selection (or require you to fight with the colors to get it to look good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like they just have a lighter border at the top and a darker border at the bottom. Nothing fancy. Didn't match the colors exactly, but you get the idea:

```css
article {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #44ccff;
  color: white;
}

article header,
article section div {
  background-color: #445; 
}
article section div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #333344;
}
article section div {
  border-top: 2px solid #556;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #223;
}
```

```html
<article>
<h2>StarterPackage</h2>
<header>Here you can type...</header>
<section>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
</section>
</article>
```

Comment: this is the exact effect i have been looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```css
body {
  background: #74D3FF;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #292B33;
  border-top: 3px solid #2C2F36;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1E2128;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #2C2F39;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jgaegvnw/4/**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example: 
HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #34495E;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.box:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #67809F;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

The box colors are as close as I can get and the borders are colored red and green so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use border inset see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/wfbkj5qs/

```
div {
  border-style: inset;
  border-bottom-color: #20242D;
  border-top-color: #363942;
  background-color: #383C47;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .table {
  background: #1e2129;
  width: 375px;
  border-radius:40 px; //this can be in px,%,em
  overflow:hidden; //or change the border radius of div's inside;

}
.row1 {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #272a34;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
.row2 {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #313641;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

here is a fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/bsmL1kx7/9/